# Pyzmq segmentation fault when binding socket

Tags: python, segmentation-fault, zeromq, pyzmq

I'm trying to get a project using ZeroMQ and Python up and running but it's segfaulting when I run the following code:

```
import zmq
context = zmq.Context()
pub_endpoint = 'tcp://127.0.0.1:23310'
pub_sock = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
pub_sock.bind(pub_endpoint)
```

The error I get is:

```
Python(10252,0x7fff70eb7cc0) malloc: *** error for object 0x1010b8e60: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Abort trap
```

I am running Python 2.7.6 with ZeroMQ 4.0.4 on OSX 10.6.8.

Comment: Are you sure about ZeroMQ version? You declare ZeroMQ 4.0.4, this version is not seen in tags of pyzmq and latest version on PyPi shows version 14.3.0 incl. version for OSX.

Comment: 4.0.4 is the version of ZeroMQ, not of PyZMQ.  I'm on the most recent PyZMQ version.